# Halt an insert in trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, order-of-execution

I'm working on a e-commerce integration and all it does is insert new opportunities with a block of text containing the details of the transaction, which I then parse out and update various fields with.

The problem is, I get an insert from the api on every change of the order status, and I want to prevent duplicate orders.
So I'm thinking on a trigger, before insert see if it's an existing order and if so parse out the changes and update the original order..

and then silently prevent the insert.

Is there a way to have a trigger prevent the insertion (ideally without error), yet not roll back the trigger's changes?

Comment: Does each entry from the e-commerce system have a unique identifier?

Comment: they have an external system order number, but it's not passing a truly unique record id. Ie Order 23423 will get get 2 inserts once when the order is saved pending and once after payment is completed. (and that order isn't guaranteed)

Answer (score 4):

The better approach in this case is to use Upsert API Call instead of Insert. Trigger are designed to throw exception when there is error and we will not be able to change it.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_upsert.htm

Comment: yeah that would be ideal but unfortunately the inserts are done by a 3rd party.